# Qt run time error in using compute function of HOG descriptor

Tags: qt, opencv, classification, feature-descriptor

I am using QT-Creater 5.2 to create a GUI to display the Image and a binary classifier to 
detect the object is present or absent using Dalal & triggs HOG extraction algorithm.

I am facing the mentioned Runtime error & need help to solve this issue.

Regards,
Sai[image: Exception Triggered Error]

mainwindow.h

```
    #ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
    #define MAINWINDOW_H

    #include <QMainWindow>
    #include<QDebug>
    #include <opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp>
    //#include <opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp>
    #include<opencv2/core/core.hpp>
    #include<opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp>
    #include<opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
    #include<opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
    #include<opencv2/ml/ml.hpp>
    #include<opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp>
    using namespace cv;

    namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow;
    }

    class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
    {
        Q_OBJECT

    public:
        explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
        ~MainWindow();
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
    #include "ui_mainwindow.h"

    MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
        QMainWindow(parent),
        ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
    {
        ui->setupUi(this);

       IplImage *oMatDeltaImage  = cvLoadImage("E:\\Wihart\\Car_Images\\(785).jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);

        Mat mat_img(oMatDeltaImage );
        float oMatResult =  SVM_classifier(mat_img);
    //    qDebug()<<oMatResult;

    }

    MainWindow::~MainWindow()
    {
        delete ui;
    }

    float SVM_classifier(Mat image)
    {

            resize(image, image, Size(64,128) );

            HOGDescriptor extract_features;
            vector<float> descriptorsValues;
            vector<Point> locations;
            extract_features.compute( image, descriptorsValues, Size(0,0), Size(0,0), locations);

            Mat feature_vector(descriptorsValues);// = Mat::zeros((descriptorsValues.size(),1));
            CvSVM SVM;
            SVM.load("SVM_classifier_data.xml");
            float result= SVM.predict(feature_vector);
            return result;
    }
```

main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
    #include <QApplication>

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        QApplication a(argc, argv);
        MainWindow w;
        w.show();

        return a.exec();
    }
```

Comment: -1 as message text is not written down in a searchable way

Comment: can you remove the `resize(0.0)` statements? why you use them? vectors have no elements when created.

Comment: Avoid posting images as descriptions (except UI/Graphics examples). Better use code and error description and try to provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: thank u,  i have modified the query as per your suggestions.